# parse_date_time() gives unexpected result when minutes are missing

Tags: r, lubridate

I often have different formatted (partial) timestamps and usually I never encounter any problems using `parse_date_time` with `truncated = 3` and set the prioritized `orders`, however recently I experienced some unexpected results.

Consider this sample vector of different formats

```
v <- c("30/11/2022 18:23", "30/11/2022 18:23:01", "2012-1-30", "11/11/20 11:12", "10-11-12")

parse_date_time(v, orders = c("dmyHMS", "ymdHMS", "ydmHMS", "mdyHMS"), truncated = 3)

[1] "2030-11-20 22:18:23 UTC" "2022-11-30 18:23:01 UTC" "2012-01-30 00:00:00 UTC" "2020-11-11 11:12:00 UTC" "2012-11-10 00:00:00 UTC"
```

All values in my vector are parsed correctly, except the first value. I do not understand why "30/11/2022 18:23" is parsed as "2030-11-20 22:18:23 UTC" instead of "2022-11-30 18:23:00 UTC" especially when you consider that `parse_date_time("30/11/2022 18:23", orders = c("dmyHMS"), truncated = 3)` indeed parses as such.

I am not sure how the truncation influences the orders, I had expected something like *dmyHMS, dmyHM, dmyH, dmy, ymdHMS, ...* but appearantly that is not what happens.

Does anyone know a solution for my case? The only workaround I can think of is to do a check if any ":"'s are in the strings, and if it is just one, append ":00" before parsing but is a bit ugly I think.

Comment: Try `parse_date_time(v, c("dmyHM", "dmyHMS", "dmy", "ymd"))`. No idea about internal orders. Obviously not a really stable solution, but "10-11-12" fits at least 2 definitions tbf.